# memory size occupied by a variable with respect to computer Science

Tags: memory, memory-management

What is the memory size occupied by a variable with a value of -1 on a 32-bit computer if a variable with the value of 1 occupies 4 bytes?

Comment: Are both the variables of the same type? Why would -1 take up a different amount of space than 1?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both variables are of type int, the width of an integer is fixed on a given platform. But in this case an integer consumes 4 bytes (i.e. 32-bits).
The maximum lower and upper limit for the integer (int) in Java is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 which includes both numbers.  It is how it gets represented internally.

So the value -1 occupies 4 bites(32-bits) memory size same as the value 1.

You might want to do some reading on integer representation, specifically two's complement representation.